# How to use Threads in WinForms C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I have a question about using threads. I have an application in WinForms. I have a start button with a method. When I click on it the method starts performing and lasts for a long time. When the method is performing the Form is not active I can't even close it until the method ends. I want to make the Form active and click on another button (Stop button) to stop method performing.

```
    private void start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StartLoading() //Some Method which performing I want to stop at any time
    }

    private void stop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Stop performing Method from start_Click
    }
```

I tryed to use the next code:

```
    private void start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread StartThread = new Thread(StartLoading);
        StartThread.Start();
    }

    public void StartLoading() 
    {
    }
```

And it works. The method is performing while the Form remains active. But I don't know how to stop this thread on stop_Click event.
Maye there is another way to do what I want??

Best Regards
Sergey

Comment: StartThread.Abort();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're doing some looping inside the thread, I would suggest you to add a variable, like this:

In your stop button, add below:

```
bool isStopped = false;
```

And inside your loop:

```
while(yourCondition)
{
    if(isStopped)
       break;
}
```

This way, it's safer and can make sure you finish current loop

But if you would like to terminate it immediately, there's a function called [Thread.Abort()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.abort(v=vs.110).aspx)

You'll have to modify the code like this:

```
Thread StartThread = null;
private void start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StartThread = new Thread(StartLoading);
    StartThread.Start();
}

public void StartLoading() 
{
    StartThread.Abort();
}
```

Comment: Note that calling `StartThread.Abort()` will raise an exception, which should be caught.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer works. It's easy and very simple. All other answers are too difficult to understand for me))

Comment: @Sergey `Thread.Abort()` [is a horrible choice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559255/whats-wrong-with-using-thread-abort), it can leave your program in a corrupted state. Don't do it.

Comment: Yes so I put a workaround, and told op if he really needs to terminate the thread immediately, then use this method

Comment: I think that Thread.Abort() is good for me. Because I will use it very seldom and only when something goes wrong and I want to stop program immediately, I will not care about its workability. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

If you want a slow action to be executed until it is finished or until you manually cancel it, you may want to use `Task` and `CancellationToken`. For me it seems like the most proper way to do this:

```
public class MyForm
{
    private CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    private Task task;

    private void buttonStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        buttonStart.Enabled = false;
        buttonCancel.Enabled = true;

        task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
            // do something extremely slow
            // and use 'ThrowIfCancellationRequested'

            for (int i = 0; i < Int32.MaxValue; i++)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(10);
                cts.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            }
        }, cts.Token).ContinueWith(t => {
            if (t.IsCanceled)
            {
                // User has cancelled loading
            }
            if (t.IsFaulted)
            {
                // Exception has occured during loading
            }
            if (t.IsCompleted)
            {
                // Loading complete
            }
        });
    }       

    private void buttonCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        buttonStart.Enabled = true;
        buttonCancel.Enabled = false;

        cts.Cancel();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you need to use `cts.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` not `if (cts.IsCancellationRequested) return;` if you want `t.IsCanceled` to return true if you cancel after the task starts. If you don't the task thinks the cancellation was requested but the method completed it's work so it marks it as `IsCompleted`.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Of course, you are right. I have edited my answer. Am I missing `try .. catch` somewhere or will it properly handle `OperationCanceledException` itself? Thank you.

Comment: If the OperationCanceledException is associated with the same token that was passed in as the 2nd argument to `StartNew` it is treated as a special case and goes to the IsCanceled state instead of the IsFaulted state. If a OperationCanceledException is raised but it was not associated with the passed in token it will show up as a faulted task.

Comment: See the MSDN page "[How to: Cancel a Task and Its Children](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537607(v=vs.110).aspx)" for a detailed example.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `BackgroundWorker` for this.

```
        private BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();

        public Form()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
            bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bw_DoWork);
            bw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bw_RunWorkerCompleted);
        }

        private void start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!bw.IsBusy)
            {
                bw.RunWorkerAsync();
            }
        }
        private void stop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation)
            {
                bw.CancelAsync();
            }
        }
        private void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

            if (worker.CancellationPending)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                return;
            }

            StartLoading(); //Some Method which performing I want to stop at any time
        }
        private void bw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Cancelled)
            {
                //"Canceled!";
            }

            else if (e.Error != null)
            {
                //"Error: " + e.Error.Message);
            }

            else
            {
                //"Done!";
            }
        }
```